# Can I deploy/add a service fabric stateless service to participate in the existing cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want the ability for clients to create their own stateless services and be able to upload/publish it to join an existing cluster. Is this doable? I understand that I need to update the application manifests dynamically but not sure how or if this is possible programmatically without side effects of the service fabric runtime processes.

The workflow is to upload the code (zipped file maybe or whatever) via an API gateway.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to keep in mind is that you do not deploy individual services to a Service Fabric cluster. You deploy applications, which can contain one or more services.

So the key question to ask is whether you need the new code to be integrated with an existing application type or not. It sounds like what you're trying to do is just enable multiple clients to deploy independent applications on a shared Service Fabric cluster, in which case you would not be modifying existing application types, but deploying entirely new ones.

Thus, you would need your API gateway to dynamically generate application and service manifests, combine them with the client-provided code to create an application package, then copy, register, and create those applications in the cluster. As far as the Service Fabric runtime is concerned, this looks no different than if you had deployed an application type built and packaged in Visual Studio. Processes running existing applications are not impacted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! My idea was the ability to deploy individual service(a stateless service) to join an existing application in the cluster. I saw the SF PartyCluster example which allows you to submit your SF app to join an existing cluster but this is at the application level.

Comment: What are you looking to gain by having the new service join the existing application?

Comment: I thought of an application that can host some code, build/compile it in the server side(genereate the EXE), add the necessary plumbings to enable it to participate in an existing SF application, then it will act like a custom Azure Function framework. Just a thought.

Comment: Ok. In that case, you won't benefit from combining the new service with an existing app - just some grouping in SF Explorer and other places where you see your app list. Think of an application as a collection of services that work _together_ to deliver some larger piece of functionality. It acts as the unit of deployment and upgrade as well as the highest level of the health reporting hierarchy. None of those concepts make sense for a set of completely independent services. There is no runtime overhead from putting services in different apps and it would be easier for you to implement.